# BigQuery query on (custom) timestamp partitioned table returns zero results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in a dataset with the following schema:

```
date TIMESTAMP
id INTEGER
...
```

The table is partitioned on the date column.

Displaying a preview of the table in the BQ UI reveals it has many rows in February:

```
date, id, ...
2019-02-19 16:18:00 UTC, 534480012, ...
2019-02-19 16:23:00 UTC, 534423879, ...
```

However, this query returns zero results:

```
SELECT id FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<table>`
WHERE 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(date, INTERVAL 60*24 HOUR) <= `date` AND
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(date, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) >= `date`
```

(And yes, as of this writing, February rows should show up.)

What's more is even the "default" query returns zero results:

```
SELECT id FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<table>` WHERE date = TIMESTAMP("2019-02-19") LIMIT 1000
```

No errors in either case. Just empty results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can this ever be true?

```
TIMESTAMP_SUB(date, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) >= `date`
```

If you subtract 24 hours, then it will be less then `date` rather than bigger than `date`.

As for your second query, you simply have no timestamps that are exactly at midnight.  Presumably, you intend something like:

```
WHERE DATE(date) = DATE('2019-02-19')
```

I strongly recommend that you change the name of the column.  Naming a column after a SQL keyword is a bad idea.  Calling something a "date" when it is really a timestamp is misleading and confusing.